# Initializer is not a constant error

Tags: c, visual-c++, console

sorry if this has been asked over and over but i just *don't get* what's wrong with this C code, since it was compiling with no problems until someday it started complaining about "C2009: Initializer is not a constant" in lines 9 and 10 of this header:

```
// CONIO2.H
#ifndef CONIO2_H_INCLUDED
#define CONIO2_H_INCLUDED
#ifndef _WINDOWS_
#include <windows.h>
#endif

void clrscr(void) {
    int Written = 0;
    COORD ord;
    ord.X = 0;
    ord.Y = 0;
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 32, 80 * 25, ord, &Written);
}

//MAIN.C
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio2.h>
```

Edit: I found the error. I was using the Eclipse CDT plugin for developing C applications but it wasn't setting up the path correctly. I had to play with the configs to make it work, but thanks anyways!

Comment: Since conio2.h isn't a compiler library but a user-made header file, including it using `#include "conio2.h"`. However, this is unlikely the cause of the error.

Comment: Are there any clues if you preprocess with `/P` and look at the function in the resulting .i file?

Answer (score 1):

```
COORD ord;
```

You are missing the definition of the `COORD` type alias. My guess is you are not including the right header: `Wincon.h`

See here for the requirements (the header to include) to use the `COORD` type alias:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682119(v=vs.85).aspx

**EDIT**: moreover you seems to have an issue with your `#ifndef` directives: there are two `#ifndef` but only one `#endif` in your header. For each `#ifndef` you need an `#endif`. And are you sure you want to include `windows.h` only when `_WINDOWS_` is not defined?

Comment: Header: Wincon.h (include Windows.h)

I do include it, in the beggining of the file.

Comment: edit: even removing the ifndef's and including windows.h in a pure and crude way, i still get the same error

Comment: The guard against #including <windows.h> is not necessary, so remove it. Windows.h should have header guards of its own.

Answer (score 0):

This link describes the error along-with some examples. It may help you. As per the link, the compiler initializes non-automatic variables at the start of the program and the values they are initialized with must be constant. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t801az8a(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Links are great to provide reference and attribution, but make for poor answers by themselves.  Would you please quote the relevant material as well so that the answer can stand by itself?

Comment: int Written = 0; // Isn't that constant!? I mean, isnt *zero* a constant value!?

Comment: IMHO, this link has exact same error, why this error is thrown and some examples showing the problem. It is self explanatory. I don't see anything irrelevant in the link.

Comment: All the examples in this code are automatic, and only "Written" is initialized, to a constant. So the link seems irrelevant to the error. Also, the code at the link seems incorrect, `2.0 - 1.0` should be pre-processed to the constant `1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several pre-processor oddities. The below code works well on a *standard* C compiler for Windows. Please note that VC++ is not a standard C compiler, so it could toss all kinds of strange errors at you.

```
// CONIO2.H
#ifndef CONIO2_H_INCLUDED
#define CONIO2_H_INCLUDED

#include <windows.h>

void clrscr (void) 
{
  DWORD Written = 0;
  COORD ord;
  ord.X = 0;
  ord.Y = 0;
  FillConsoleOutputCharacter (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 
                              32, 
                              80 * 25, 
                              ord, 
                              &Written);
}

#endif /* CONIO2_H_INCLUDED */

//MAIN.C

#include <stdio.h>
#include "conio2.h"
```

Comment: Oh sorry, not oddities. The guard was to make sure that windows.h was included, because i was including it in some files but not in the others, and it got messed up so i though of a way to clean that only changing the header file. Also, conio2.h **is** in the compiler's include path, so i really prefer to use <conio2.h> :)